# Data Compression Algorithms: Compress String

Tags: java, file, security, compression

So, I'm basically developing a desktop app where you provide a file and it compresses it for and gives it back to you in compressed string format. What I mean by that is that I read the bytes of the files, compress those bytes and then basically convert them into a raw .txt file. The conversion process is easy, what I'm trying to find out is how to compress the file. I know I want to do loss-less data compression because that's how I'm going to get the file decompressed, but I just don't know which compression algorithm to use or if I need to program something myself.

For example:

```
public String CompressFile(Bytes fileInformation[]) {
   for(int i = 0; i < fileInformation; i++) {
      if(fileInformation[i].equals(fileInformation[i + 1]) {
        // Say that the file has two instances of the same byte than no need to 
        // include it twice or thrice.
      }
   }
}
```

Above is a very basic example. But I want something more sophisticated that can compress files until what is left is true entropy or randomness. No more compressing, that is as random as you can get. And from that data, I can decompress the file and present it to the user when he provides me the compressed data. In simple words, I would like to use a compression algorithm that is efficient, fast, works and is powerful. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
To word this better, I need to compress or downscale the string or sequence of bytes that a file contains, and not the file itself.

**The main point of this question is that I want to compress an int array. Like if I have an array {1, 4, 5, 1, 4} then I want to group the ones and fours together. It is not that useful, but as the array upscales the compression algorithm can help reduce the length of the array by a big amount.**

Comment: Why can't you use Java's built-in compression utilities?

Comment: Because I need to compress the string of the sequence of bytes and not the file itself. The [Deflater/Inflater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html)  class are okay but I need something faster, simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Have you tried https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/zip.html or other third party library?  They do support more algorithms.

Comment: Your question is extremely broad and this cannot be done "in general" on a data stream. Compression relies on the statistical properties of the data source in order to compress frequent patterns with less bits. It the source is a file, it can be analysed. But if you do not want to analyse previously the file, you need a very good statistical model of your stream, otherwise even the best compression method (on a certain type of source) may increase the amount data (if the actual source differs from the model).

Comment: I have the bytes or better the pixels contained in the image. My question is about whether there is any compression algorithm that can compress an int array.

Comment: There is *no* compression algorithm that can compress *all* int arrays. Now if you have some statistical properties of your array, you can design some compression algorithm. For images, *many* work has been done to model their behavior and it is used in standard compression methods. If you need to compress images, use them.

Comment: So, instead of using array compression, I should instead use image compression. Is that correct?

Comment: If you want to compress images, jpg or jpg2k are very efficient. Or png if you want lossless compression. But they will not compress "strings" as stated in the title of the question.

Comment: Oh okay great, thanks for the information. Found png compression and it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I now understand this question is quite irrelevant. What I wanted was a way to compress data, because my memory couldn't handle it. But now I realize that instead of that what I should have been doing was reading the file in chunks so it doesn't matter if I compress it or not. And this is how to do it:

```
try {
    File file = new File("myFile");
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
    int chunkLen = 0;
    while ((chunkLen = is.read(chunk)) != -1) {
        // your code..
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfE) {
    // file not found, handle case
} catch (IOException ioE) {
    // problem reading, handle case
}
```

As for the compression function, if anyone wants there is this great [LZW Compression](https://github.com/tonyking97/java-lzw-compression) algorithm written by [tonyking97](https://github.com/tonyking97) and basically you have to convert your byte array into a string, then pass it through this compression function. It works, but it is slow with big byte arrays.

Of course, for writing the file again we have to use the [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileOutputStream.html) instead of [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileInputStream.html) and say [`outputStream.write(byte[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29). Hope this will help somebody :)